# \textcite for same authors different years - Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, multiple-citations

I want to add a textual citation for three papers, two of which are by the same authors but in different years.
I am using these codes in my preamble

```
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
    {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
    {}%
   \multicitedelim}
 {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
```

This is the code for printing the references section

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
```

This is the code for inserting the in-text citation

```
\textcite{azar2019measuring, azar2020concentration, azar2022labor}
```

But the output is "Azar et al. (2019); 2022; Azar et al. (2020)"

Why is the 2022 paper listed by itself without parentheses? I want the output to be
"Azar et al. (2019;2022); Azar et al. (2020)"

Any help?

Comment: Please also add the three entries from the `.bib` file to make it easier to reproduce the issue. Preferably you should also provide a more complete document around your code snippet, with documentclass, begin/end document, printbibliography, so that people that want to answer your question don't have to type that themselves and can immediately start looking into the issue.

Comment: You declared the existing `biblatex` command `\textcite`. What is the result of the original `\textcite`. In other words, delete your `DeclareCiteCommand{}` (or comment it out) and recompile your document. See what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Al alchemist suggested in their comment, the standard `\textcite` works, I only modified the delimiters.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bib.bib}
@inproceedings{azar2019measuring,
  title={Measuring labor market power two ways},
  author={Azar, Jos{\'e} and Marinescu, Ioana and Steinbaum, Marshall},
  booktitle={AEA Papers and Proceedings},
  volume={109},
  pages={317--21},
  year={2019}
}
@article{azar2020concentration,
  title={Concentration in US labor markets: Evidence from online vacancy data},
  author={Azar, Jos{\'e} and Marinescu, Ioana and Steinbaum, Marshall and Taska, Bledi},
  journal={Labour Economics},
  volume={66},
  pages={101886},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{azar2022labor,
  title={Labor market concentration},
  author={Azar, Jos{\'e} and Marinescu, Ioana and Steinbaum, Marshall},
  journal={Journal of Human Resources},
  volume={57},
  number={S},
  pages={S167--S199},
  year={2022},
  publisher={University of Wisconsin Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\textcitedelim}{\addsemicolon\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\addsemicolon\addspace}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{azar2019measuring, azar2020concentration, azar2022labor}

\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]

\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. = I downloaded the bibitems from Google Scholar, I don't know if they are the ones you're using. Next time please add a complete MWEB: [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)